# How to use onNewIntent() in AppCompatActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I have Main Activity (A) with searchView which goes to another SearchResultActivity (B1) which shows search results.

I want to have searchView in this second Activity too, so if user wants to write another request, he doesn't have to go back. 
It means when user enters request from SearchResultActivity, another instance of SearchResultActivity (B2) is fired.

After that, if user presses up button on toolbar, it goes back to activity A, as it should, because A is specified as B's parent. 
But the problem is, when you press back button from B2, it goes back to B1, instead of A.

I read this article, 
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en
where author explains that you shouldn't create new instances of the same activity, instead flag the activity as

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

on manifest and use onNewIntent() method to reuse the same activity. It's exactly what I need.

But I can't override this onNewIntent() method, because apparently it's not present in AppCompatActivity, which I'm using. 
Is there any way to use onNewIntent() with AppCompatActivity? Or it works only on Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I can't override this onNewIntent() method, because apparently it's not present in AppCompatActivity

[`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) is a descendant of [`FragmentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html), which has protected method [`onNewIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)).

Double check your imports.

Comment: Yes, I found that there was a problem with import statements. I was able to override it.
Thanks.

Comment: can you clarify what was wrong with your imports? having the same issue